# Getting Multiple Invoke activities on Adaptive card actions in Android device for Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: android, botframework, microsoft-teams

We have implemented an `Interactive adaptive card` for one of our requirements, where are providing an `adaptive card` with the simple `action button`.

When the user **clicks/tap** on the button we will handle the activity on the bot and will respond accordingly to the user either with an error message or an updated adaptive card.

This flow works completely fine on the **Microsoft Teams desktop** application and a **web client**. However, we are facing the following issues with the **Android application**.

1. Even when we respond with an error it's not reflecting the error on the adaptive card.
2. It is sending multiple invoke activity requests to the bot because of that our activity handling logic is also being executed twice. that causes an issue in user experience

Following is the code block that we've implemented.

```js
async onInvokeActivity(turnContext: TurnContext): Promise<InvokeResponse> {
        // handling of the activity and API requests to the backend system.
// in case user login is required initiate login flow using auth card and return error response to the adaptive card.

// generate response and respond with appropriate.

    }
```

Link used for reference.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/bot-basics?tabs=javascript

Comment: Could you please share some minimal code and document which you are referring?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT Added details to the question.

Comment: We are able to repro your issue. On click of action button the invokeactivity executed two times and the message get displyed twice. We have raised a bug for it. We will let you know once we get updates on it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is an expected behavior.**

For 5XX errors (500-504), Android will retry the "invoke" (any) service again, so the "invokeActivity" called twice.

Please fix the error in Bot. For success case this would not be called twice.